# Regex to find strings like "@*1*@"

Tags: regex

Could you please help me to write regex clause for finding strings like

```
"@*1*@"  "@*2*@" "@*AAA*@"
```

Comment: @stribizhev you right, except SO is not a forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one you can use: `@\*[0-9A-Z]+\*@`.

Here is a [sample](https://regex101.com/r/cU2zZ4/1).